# Are the very hyperlows closed under join?

Tags: computability-theory

Call $X$ *very hyperlow* if $\mathcal{O}^X \le_T \mathcal{O}$, where $\mathcal{O}$ is your favorite $\Pi^1_1$-complete set.  Note: Turing reducibility, not hyp-reducibility.  Observe that this is a (Turing) degree invariant notion.

Are the very hyperlow Turing degrees closed under join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. There is an $\mathscr{O}$-recursive sequence $\{D_i\}_{i}$ of dense open sets so that for any real $g$ meeting every member of the sequence, $\mathscr{O}^g\leq_T g\oplus \mathscr{O}$. Now it is simple to construct two such reals $g_1$ and $g_2$ so that $g_1\oplus g_2\equiv_T \mathscr{O}$.

Comment: Nice, thank you.